# error when link is chrome:// dino but works for every other link #2264

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

#### System info

- Playwright Version: [v1.XX]
- Operating System: [Windows 11 latest]
- Browser: chrome

#### Source code

```
import asyncio
import logging
import os
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from scraper.capt import capt
from dotenv import load_dotenv

total_tabs = 10
link = "chrome://dino/"

async def main() -> None:
    env_fn = load_dotenv()
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        filename='logs/logs.log'
    )
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        # browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        # browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False, args=['--no-sandbox'])
        # context = await browser.new_context()
        # context not needed as here using more windows is better than tabs ig since it can be parallel but not sure if tabs can be parallelized
        launch = await capt(browser=browser,logger=logger,n=total_tabs,link=link).open_n_tabs()
        # await context.close()
        await browser.close()
        logger.info("---closing browser---")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # asyncio.run(main())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

- [yes ] I provided exact source code that allows reproducing the issue locally.

If the link is for example https://www.google.com/ it works perfectly fine but Im trying to create a reinforcement learning model on dino game so i want to access the chrome://dino link then im getting this error...

```
PS M:\dino tut> & C:/Users/hp/anaconda3/python.exe "m:/dino tut/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m:\dino tut\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "m:\dino tut\main.py", line 26, in main
    launch = await capt(browser=browser,logger=logger,n=total_tabs,link=link).open_n_tabs()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "m:\dino tut\scraper\capt.py", line 19, in open_n_tabs
    await page.goto(self.link)
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\playwright\async_api\_generated.py", line 9275, in goto
    await self._impl_obj.goto(
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_page.py", line 484, in goto
    return await self._main_frame.goto(**locals_to_params(locals()))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_frame.py", line 149, in goto
    await self._channel.send("goto", locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 63, in send
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 495, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 101, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
playwright._impl._errors.Error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED at chrome://dino/
```

what i dont get is why is internet disconnected for only this specific site and not some other issue like unable to access the site